# Content Security Policy does not respect meta tag

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, youtube, content-security-policy, production

I get the following error in the Chrome's web console on my deployed React app:

```
Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

However, I have specified `frame-src` in my `index.html` like in the following snippet:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src https://www.youtube.com/">
```

The source for the error is a YouTube embed, and with the meta tag in place the embed works fine on localhost. What could cause this error only to appear on a deployed React app?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding Content-Security-Policy header on the server. So it wasn't an issue with the front-end code after all.